# Vault is not appearing in Consul(ui) services list

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul, hashicorp-vault

Configs:

- **consul-config.json**:

```
{
    "datacenter": "localhost",
    "data_dir": "/consul/data",
    "log_level": "DEBUG",
    "server": true,
    "ui": true,
    "ports": {
      "dns": 53
    }
}
```

- **vault-config.json**:

```
{
  "ui": true,
  "backend": {
    "consul": {
      "address": "consul:8500",
      "path": "vault/"
    }
  },
  "listener": {
    "tcp":{
      "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_disable": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

1. Vault appears in services list of consul, when i've used:

   - consul - **v1.7.2**
   - vault - **v1.3.4**

[image]

2. **But**, when i'm using another versions, there's no vault service in the list(in consul ui):

   - consul - **v1.6.5**
   - vault - **v1.4.0**

[image]

Here's some info from logs:

[image]

I need solution to use 2nd variant, i searched stackoverflow, documentation and other resources, but there's no any solution, maybe i skipped :).
Have you experienced like this ?

Comment: Is `"address": "consul:8500"` the consul-cluster or a consul-agent ? The container logs usually give some info.

Comment: I added log info, i think it's consul-agent